# Passing Hashtable to Unmanaged code using interop

Tags: c#, .net, interop

How can i pass `HashTable` in .net to c++ using interop?

I know how to pass primitive types but need to know how can I pass the other ones.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot pass the entire object to be used as a hash table in C++. P/invoke translate the .NET type to a type C++ can understand. For example, `String` is converted to a `LPWSTR` (`wchar_t *`). However it cannot convert something like a `HashSet` in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

There is no C++ parameter type to which you can pass a Hashtable (except a `void*`, which wouldn't do you any good)

Instead, you need to create a C++ `struct` to hold the information in the `hashtable`, port the `struct` to C#, then marshal the `struct`.